# .populate() returning empty array?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'm working on project and I am trying to get the users reviews to display on the page. However whenever I run my application it returns an empty array and I'm not sure why, I have no issue with the getReviews function as it returns everything correctly, but getUserReviews just returns an empty array with no error. I've tried multiple methods and just can't seem to get it

Review Model

```js
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    const Review = mongoose.model(
      "Review",
      new mongoose.Schema({
        movieId: String,
        reviewId: String,
        content: String,
        sentimentScore: String,
        author: [
          {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
          }
        ],
        reponseTo: [
            {
              type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              ref: "User"
            },
        ]
      })
    );
    
    module.exports = Review;
```

User Model

```js
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    const User = mongoose.model(
      "User",
      new mongoose.Schema({
        username: String,
        email: String,
        password: String,
        roles: [
          {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Role"
          }
        ]
      })
    );
    
    module.exports = User;
```

Review Routes

```js
    const express =  require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const {authJwt} = require("../middlewares");
    const Review = require("../models/review.model")
    
    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
          res.header(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
          );
          next();
    });
    
    
    router.post("/addReview", [authJwt.verifyToken], (req, res) => {
        const review = new Review(req.body)
    
        review.save((err, review) => {
            if(err) return res.json({success:false, err})
            
            Review.find({'_id': review._id})
            .populate('author')
            .exec((err, result) => {
                if(err) return res.json({success: false, err})
                return res.status(200).json({success: true, result})
            })
        })
        
    })
    
    router.post("/getReviews", [authJwt.verifyToken], (req, res) => {
        Review.find({"movieId": req.body.data}) 
        // console.log("ID ", req.body.data)
        .populate('author')
        .exec((err, reviews) => {
            if(err) return res.status(400).send(err)
            res.status(200).json({success: true, reviews})
        })
        
    })

    router.post("/getUserReviews", [authJwt.verifyToken], (req, res) => {
        Review.find({"userId": req.body.data}) 
        .populate({
            path: 'author.user',
            model: 'Review'})
        .exec((err, reviews) => {
            if(err) return res.status(400).send(err)
            res.status(200).json({success: true, reviews})
        })
        
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to query **Review** collection with `userId` field, and **Review** collection does not have `userId` field in its model definition.

Maybe you wanted to query `author` array? In that case, try this:

```js
router.post("/getUserReviews", [authJwt.verifyToken], (req, res) => {
    Review.find({ author: req.body.data }) 
    .populate('author')
    .exec((err, reviews) => {
        if(err) return res.status(400).send(err)
        res.status(200).json({success: true, reviews})
    })
    
})
```

Comment: that was originally how I had it, just tried again and the array unfortunately still returns empty

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it?